# Windows explorer keyboard search timeout

Tags: keyboard, windows-explorer

In windows explorer (in Windows 7, at least, and I think most other versions) you can type the name of a folder or file and the highlight bar will follow your keystrokes until you stop typing for a moment. For example, if your directory contains the following:

```
example.txt
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

you can type "file3" to get to the file3.txt item. However, if you type "fil" and then pause for a moment and then type "e", the previous keystrokes are lost, and example.txt gets highlighted.

Is there any setting (registry or other) that will allow me to increase the amount of time that must elapse before the prior keystrokes are erased from whatever buffer explorer uses?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.
R.